# Space issues with Mac Pro OSX 10.7.5 with SSD 120G as boot volume

Tags: macos, finder, ssd

Issue is most obvious in Final Cut Pro (10.0.8), but has occurred with other apps. I can't find a way to lower the footprint on the SSD. I only have one user (me) and have nearly all the apps on the regular hard drive. No big data. Finder says my user directory is using 75.5G but there are only about 1G of files listed under the user directory. I understand there are lots of hidden files, but over 70G? Is this just an FCP issue, or am I missing something completely. Would the $20 for upgrading to mountain lion fix the issue?

Comment: I can’t remember the disk footprint of OS X Lion vs. Mountain Lion, but I don’t think the difference is significant. I think FCP stores a lot of files in the `/Users/Shared` directory, which might explain the discrepancy. Two good applications for seeing where disk space is being used are [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/) and [DaisyDisk](http://www.daisydiskapp.com/), which might be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Funnily enough I also have the same problem now. I don't remember space on my hard drive being taken so much but my 120GB SSD has only 40GB left now too. Using DiskInventory X i know that 40 is taken up by my iTunes library and some other files, but 40Gb seems to have been used by OS. I'm sure it wasn't more than 20 when I installed the SSD.

Comment: Problem solved - space was taken by Time Machine local back-ups. Disabling that (as I back up to a NAS at home) stopped it and deleted the old backups too.